# Is it possible to downgrade a business/first class flight to economy without the ticket purchaser knowing?

Tags: air-travel, luxury

Suppose a rich relative has invited you to visit, or maybe a generous company is [sending you to a conference](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/FieldGuidetoDevelopers.html), and they buy you a ticket in first class. But you feel like this is either a waste of money, or you're petite and don't *like* the larger seats, or you want to minimize your carbon footprint, or whatever other motivation you may have...

Is it possible to *downgrade* your ticket without the purchaser knowing?  Ideally, with a little $$ (in the form of future flight credit, no doubt) left in *your* pocket for future travel?

Comment: It would be nice if you could refund he whole ticket and take a bus ;)

Comment: @MeNoTalk I have good experience with transatlantic buses.

Comment: @Bernhard lol, technically speaking Airbus is a transatlantic bus ;)

Comment: @MeNoTalk: On a more serious note, it might be preferred to downgrade the ticket on the same flight, especially if someone is planning to wait for you at the airport to pick you up. Even a change of flights could complicate matters if, say, your flight was delayed, but the original one is not.  Your rich uncle would catch on pretty quickly that you pocketed some of his $$.

Comment: @Flimzy Lets assume it can be changed, your uncle being mad at you is acceptable compared to submitting your boarding pass to the company (as many companies require), the company will know it for sure it will be a big embarrassment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is, it would only be possible for the money refunded to go back to the purchasor. Interesting question! What I would do is this: phoen the airline and say "I want to completely cancel this ticket, and get all the money back, but 'I' want the money, not my Uncle who bought it for me."  If they say yes, you have the $$.  Then, buy a discount ticket elsewhere.

Comment: `Is it possible to downgrade your ticket without the purchaser knowing`. Email confirmation will be sent if one was provided, unless booked through an agent. The agent might inform the original booker. Might need to bribe the agent. Charges will be only reverted back to the card(unless cash was used), which was used while booking. I seriously doubt any merchant will revert back to a different card. And if points/flight credit, I believe they might use the frequent flier number provided while booking.

Comment: @DumbCoder: Since when does flight credit go to a "card"? When you cancel an economy flight, you are usually issued flight credit. I realize with first class you usually have a refundable ticket, so a refund would be possible, but the question specifically asks about getting flight credit (for the obvious reasons you mention).

Comment: Hi Flimz .. hmm, the question is **about first class tickets**, is it not??  Whenever you refund or cancel a first class ticket, you get the money back.  (It always goes to the card.)  i don't even know what a "flight credit" is, sorry.  When cancelling a first class ticket, I've never seen anything other than just a refund to the card ??  (Re business.. . same ??)

Comment: Flimz -- GMTA !!!!  the only thing I was thinking now though buddy ... I guess, so far as I have seen, 1st class tickets are pretty much always totally unrestricted.  (indeed, one of their major advantages and the reason for the insane cost.)  maybe i'm just plain wrong on that?  maybe they're sometimes restricted?  But I think in the spirit of this interesting "hypothetical" question, you'd see 1st class tickets as their usual wildly unrestricted selves...

Comment: @pnuts: That's a good suggestion! I wonder if you could simply "buy miles" with the difference? I know most FF programs allow purchasing miles--I don't know if they allow that ahead of time.

Comment: not that in matters in terms of answering the question, but this is stealing. it was not your money to spend and is not your money now.

Comment: @sgroves: No, once someone gives you something, it's yours to do as you please with. Being a benefactor (or worse yet, employer) does not give you a right to control the people you give things to.

Comment: The question is about rich relatives or whatever, rather than an employment situation but IME most companies demand the *boarding* pass rather than the receipt in order to grant a reimbursement to prevent employees from expensing unrestricted business class fares and then traveling cattle class (stealing money and arriving in worse shape than the employer paid for).

Comment: @r.. that's not the case here. the asker is not being "given" a flight as a gift; someone is paying to transport the asker somewhere. when someone pays for your flight, they are not giving you anything. they're doing you a favor. perhaps it's not "stealing", but it's extremely tacky to try and squeeze some cash out of something like that. *extremely*. like, i would never even *fathom* doing this; it just feels SO wrong.

Comment: If the ticket is for employer-provided travel, rather than a gift, swapping it for a cheaper ticked plus some other benefit could get the employer into an accounting and/or tax error - employee travel expenses are typically different from e.g. an employee bonus.

Answer (score 7):

Downgrading a flight maybe possible. It would depend on whether your ticketed fare allows you to do that. However, you may have issues if it was bought by a company as they may have used their corporate accounts and refunds (and partials) would go there. Even if it didn't they would notice they received less corporate air miles (or equivalent depending on the airline) for your flight compared to what they expected. And finally if they requested the ticket copy, it will show the fare class you flew especially on your phone as it would be on your phone. You maybe able to bypass that last one by printing out the boarding pass first (as higher classes generally allow earlier check-in) then changing the ticket.

You maybe able pull a sly one on your uncle unless he checks your booking online. Which the company could do too.

It wouldn't be the best idea to downgrade a flight without informing the purchaser first.

Comment: what you say about a corporate card buying it: indeed that applies to any card at all: for many years now it's only been possible to refund something, to, the same card in question. 'cross-refunds' have been totally out of the card industry (worldwide, I'm sure) for years now, I guess  :O

Comment: usually (among my business-travel friends who get it at least) the indivudual gets the air miles, NOT the company.

Comment: @MarkMayo British Airways has Company Travel rewards. http://www.britishairways.com/travel/on-business-how-it-works/public/en_us?source=MNVCOM1how_it_works&link=main_nav The company earns points and the travelers earn avios (air miles)

Comment: @Vagish today I learned! I figured that might be the case, but wanted to point out that it's not happening for everone.

Comment: Come to think of it this answer is, I guess, simply wrong, because: *"Downgrading a flight may be possible"* you can always totally flexibly adjust a 1st class ticket. And: *"if bought by a company .... refunds would go there"* In every case, 100.0% of the time, any refunds of the excess amount **must go and can only go to** the rich relative.

Comment: @MarkMayo That's somewhat dependent on where you live.  I can't find them ATM, but have seen pointed out on a few recent questions on Workplace.SE that German law views claiming personal rewards for anything purchased by your employer as theft and grounds for firing even if it's only a few cents on your store rewards card.

Comment: This answer is simply unfortunately "totally wrong". I've checked thoroughly and if you get a refund, the money goes straight to the purchasor.  (Just as you'd expect.)  unfortunately the answer is plain wrong.

Answer (score 6):

> But you feel like this is either a waste of money

It's a) not your money, b) already spent , c) the airlines need the cash.

> or you're petite and don't like the larger seats

Walk into economy, find someone you like the looks of, trade seats.

If you want to be cruel, find a mother with an infant.

> or you want to minimize your carbon footprint,

Won't change. The carbon footprint stays the same whether the plane is empty, half full, or stuffed to the rafters with [tribbles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribble). Where you actually sit is irrelevant.

Most airlines with online booking ( I think that's everyone except the dodgier African carriers) let anyone with the reservation code and the passenger's name look at (but not change) the reservation details. They would see. And unless it's a cash ticket (highly unlikely) any refund would go back on the purchaser's card, not yours.

So, it seems to really be a question of "what do you do when they find out".

Comment: `The carbon footprint stays the same wether the plane is empty, half full, or stuffed to the rafters with tribbles. Where you actually sit is irrelevant.` -- Perhaps true for a single flight, but not true in the grander scheme. If fewer people fly first class, the airline will allocate fewer first class seats, thus reducing the average per-passenger carbon footprint.

Comment: @Flimzy the entire "carbon footprint" thingy is nonsense, and thus irrelevant.

Comment: @jwenting: Well, the carbon footprint thing is really not the point of the question, so I agree it's irrelevant. But it's the same line of reasoning as someone who chooses to take the bus over an airplane to reduce their carbon footprint. I think it's pretty ridiculous to say it's nonsense (unless you're making that claim in a general sense that caring about one's carbon footprint is nonsense--I have no real opinion on that).

Comment: If you were to remove the condescending rebuttals to the various possible (irrelevant) reasons for wanting to downgrade, I wouldn't have a problem with this answer.  Or if you were even to make them less condescending.

Comment: I believe it's **specifically suggested** on this site to **not** criticize the reasons for a question.  Also I believe frankly you have completely misunderstood the question, which is a good one. This should be deleted.

Comment: Why is it cruel to find a mother with an infant?

Comment: what, 1st is often packed with kids these days, it's so trendy for celebs etc. to "have kids".  (however if i'm not mistaken, kids are banned in some airlines first class right?)

Comment: Just FTR I realise this answer was a joke but generally the staff would **not let you** trade seats from economy to first.  Generally they are very down on situations like when the CEO in 1st tries to bring up a lowly staffer from economy or whatever for a chat. the other 1st class pax would freak out if someone from economy was in 1st.

Comment: Incidentally, if it were in fact possible to downgrade and get something for it, keeping the first class ticket would create opportunity costs so that the money already spent effectively becomes your money to spend or recover, whether you want to see it as such or not.

Comment: @JoeBlow: There are documented [examples of such exchanges](http://www.foxnews.com/entertainment/2014/06/27/amy-adams-gives-first-class-airline-seat-to-soldier-sits-in-coach-passenger/).  That doesn't mean a first class passenger can bring an economy passenger to sit with them; they have to give up their seat in exchange.

Comment: @JoeBlow : the answer is not a joke - you can trade your first-class seat with someone if you want. You cannot, of course, upgrade someone else. Commonly done with US servicemen, and if you swap boarding passes after the ID check at the gate the airline staff won't know.

Comment: @pnuts Oh, but it was really what “that farce” was about. You expressed you disagreement there, but the result of the votes is still pretty clear.

Comment: "you can trade your first-class seat with someone if you want"  I'm pretty sure that's simply wrong dude.  You cannot trade seats on a flight.  "staff won't know" in first class it's quite common they check your ID as well as the boarding pass, since so much money is at stake: furthermore, in 1st they sort of just know who's who and keep an eye.  note that generally with today's intense security, you can't go around swapping boarding passes and the like.  Regarding "you can trade your first-class seat with someone if you want" phone an airline and ask, no point discussing it here.

Comment: @JoeBlow I refer you to the article referenced by Ben, and numerous anecdotal references on the internet at large. The cabin crew will have a lot of difficulty when no one is complaining, and the PR fallout would make SouthWest look generous. I agree it won't happen through the call center - that's a lot of re-ticketing.

Comment: Re the carbon footprint won’t change: it might not change whether you are sitting in first or economy but it certainly *does* change for an empty flight as a lighter plane burns less fuel.

Answer (score 3):

### Summary

Your scheme is absolutely, definitely, 100% impossible, because: **any excess amount refunded must and can only go to the purchasor**, the rich relative.

So that's that.

Note however that regarding the first-explained aspect of your Caper, the answer is positively yes. A primary reason (rich!) people give 1st class tickets as presents is that they are totally flexible.  If one is ever lucky enough to get a 1st class ticket somewhere as a present (it's certainly never happened to me, tragically!) you can just call the airline and change anything you want. Yes sir, no sir, three bags full sir.

---

However, here's some ***astounding information*** on this:

Thanks to DC below, it appears that some (all?) airlines now offer "cheap, incredibly crappy" first class fares.  in the Lufthansa example, I checked near dates and they only offered what (I would have thought of as) ordinary 1st class fares (to wit: obviously one can utterly freely change anything one wishes, at any time). However, a couple of weeks out, you can buy these "Easyjet-like" first class fares!  :)  which have restrictions and change fees and the like.  So, consider this factor when implementing the Caper described by the OP.

Note that, with for example a €6000 "real" 1st class ticket given to you by the rich relative, after you refunded it, paid the €500 fee, and bought a €308 cheap ticket on a discount airline instead, you'd still be ahead  €5000 in this "caper" suggested by the OP.

But again — very simply — **all refunds today go only to the purchasing credit card**, so the Caper wouldn't work. Thanks again, DC, for this "first class information"!

[image: Screenshot of flight booking prices]

Comment: Non-refundable non-changable first class tickets do exist on some airlines!

Comment: bizarre! but i believe you if you say so! (why would people buy them, it seems to me one perhaps the primary benefit of 1st class tix you know?!)

Comment: @JoeBlow: Because you want leg room, and you're certain you won't cancel :)

Comment: lol on the leg room!  you know it would be cool to see some examples of restricted 1e tickets.  I mean in certain situations that would be an awesome money saver.

Comment: @JoeBlow - Actually, most first class tickets are somewhat restricted. Even if they can be cancelled, they are typically subject to a cancellation fee (say, USD 200). Classically, these are the "A" class fares, whereas totally unrestricted first class fares typically book into the "F" class. This can be seen quite well when trying to book a trans-atlantic flight with Lufthansa, which make these restrictions quite explicit.

Comment: pnuts - I've often been fascinated by that marketing question. I feel the reasons people pony for 1e are (1) the staggering convenience associated with the ancillary aspects of the ticket more than the flight itself (so, arrive any time, phone special lines instantly and have anything done, special rooms, laugh! at procedures and rules, etc) then (2) as you say avoid the hoi polloi (Kylie Minogue: "I'm never turning right going on to a plane again") and (3) that there are less people in the cabin. Nobody eats in first, they just have a little champagne & water. Seats = no biggie. My take!!

Comment: @JoeBlow You really ought to eat in first if you can, food can be amazing. [See this blog post](http://www.headforpoints.com/2014/07/19/lufthansa-first-class-reviewed-munich-to-newark/) for an example of what the food can be like, if you find yourself there. (BA's isn't quite as good, but isn't bad)

Comment: you know i've never flown LH much!  looks great! happy trails...

Comment: pnuts - there's no apostrophe in PAs (or any plural) dude!

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on how the "ticket" is provided to you but assuming it is an airline printed ticket rather than an e-Ticket;

A lot of tickets have AGT/REF endorsements which means any refund must go back to the purchaser via the agent.

However, instead of a refund, you could ask the airline to re-issue your lower class ticket and issue the difference in Miscellaneous Charge Orders (MCOs) which are the airlines equivalent of credit notes/gift vouchers. MCOs are generally only issued by IATA airline members. MCOs can be used for part-payment of flights, excess baggage etc

Unless the original ticket was issued with an airline specific restriction, MCOs are also valid to redeem with any other IATA airline!!

Lastly, flexible airline tickets are usually valid for 12 months but you can extend their validity by having the ticket re-issued before their expiry.

Comment: Amazing - you're sure they will issue "MCOs" to the FLYER, not the purchasor?  That seems incredible.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can't get the money, you can almost surely opt to sit in economy seating. Just get to the boarding area early and inform them you'd rather be seated in economy, and I'm sure they'll be happy to open up another seat they can charge somebody else a fee to "upgrade" to.

Comment: Or just start taking bids to trade seats in the boarding area. - haha